# Can no longer deploy prompts after Spring 22 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, spring22

After the Spring 22 release,  trying to deploy any prompt file results in:

```
force-app/main/default/prompts/MyPrompt.prompt-meta.xml  Not available for deploy for this organization
```

What's the fix for this?

Comment: Is In-App Guidance also missing in `Setup` in that org?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves when I search setup's quick find box for "In-App Guidance" nothing comes up. Is this something we need to configure?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is an active Inv (W-10413641) logged on this issue, will update once I have more inputs/details along with KI(if any) and I cannot see this issue in my Spring'22 org.

*Update*: Please review Known Issue [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002Zo34QAC).

Thanks